# puppet hanging or long time on rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0

Tags: puppet, strace, hanging

In our setup, we manage our servers using puppet. Since a few days I saw the puppet client 
running very slow. When stracing the puppet process I get loads of

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? What is this process waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

Puppet is blocked somewhere in the execution...

Are you running strace on the daemon or are you running the puppet process by hand?

Can you tell what is supposed to be happening at that point? What is being executed from the manifest? What happens if you run puppet manually on the client?

This reminds me of [this bug](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/509), so it's probably been fixed in an update. I tend not to run puppet as a daemon for this reason.

Comment: when running the puppetd --test --debug, I see the process hanging on 

    debug: Executing '/usr/bin/test 0 != 0'
and
    debug: Time for triggering 2 events to edges: 7.05641293525696 

So it seems it hang on the triggering... (this is what is looks like to me)

The puppetd we are running is much newer than the one in the thread you mention so I presume we have a patched version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on my own question was: I was doing stuff in git which caused puppet to wait for GIT. The problem wasn't really puppet but it was git taking too much time. I am investigating it further and I will post the solution when found.

Comment: 7 years later... found any solution?

Comment: We just went with it and, due to some other changes, the git problem was no issue anymore.